# Unable to create customer using curl command

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, curl

I am new to magento. I am facing an issue will trying to create customer using curl command. I am passing the correct json values as customer data as well, but still getting decoding error.Can some one please help!

This is the command that I am using for creating the customer:

> curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers"
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer pvcp6auic4likpucpi07peas89hxivhe" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
>   "{"customer":{"email":email@gmail.com","firstname":"first","lastname":"last","storeId":1,"websiteId":1}}"

The error thrown is {"message":"Decoding error."}

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `"(double quotes)` with `'(single quotes)` at outer json data like below:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers" -H "Authorization: Bearer pvcp6auic4likpucpi07peas89hxivhe" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"customer":{"email":"email@gmail.com","firstname":"first","lastname":"last","storeId":1,"websiteId":1}}'
```

Comment: I tried with single quotes as well..but still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its works for me,

```
    curl -X POST "http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xhfyo8cfvknpyd5dwuupe34uosh6tuhj"  -d '{"customer": {"email": "test@gmail.com","firstname": "FirstName","lastname": "LastName","storeId": 1,"websiteId": 1}}'
```

let me know if have issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with the above command, still the same decoding error. :(     The command that I used here is : curl -X POST "http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer pvcp6auic4likpucpi07peas89hxivhe"  -d '{"customer": {"email": "test@gmail.mobi","firstname": "FirstName","lastname": "LastName","storeId": 1,"websiteId": 1}}'

Comment: are using any required custom attribute for customer.. and post your full error

Comment: The error here is  curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column1  culr: (6) COuldn't resolve host 'gmail.com,firstname' curl:(6) couldn't resolve host "FirstName,lastname' curl: (6) couldn't resolve host 'LastName,storeId' curl: (6) couldn't resolve host '1,websiteId' curt: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2

Comment: no am not using any custom attributes for customer..

Comment: i update the answer, try that, let me know if you have issue.

Comment: the token that I am using is from this uri: /magento2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token..Is it correct?
 ...beacuse am able to get the details of customers and products but I am unable to update or create it using POST..

Comment: And I believe this is not the issue with my json data .because i even validated the json that I am sending across...and i think the issue is with my token, as it is unable to post data to magento server. what do u think?

Comment: Am able to create the customer from the service class that i developed.               String customerData = "{\"customer\": { \"email\": \"email@gmail.com\",\"firstname\": \"first\",\"lastname\": \"last\", \"storeId\": 1, \"websiteId\": 1}}";
and then making a post call to "/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers"